# Why is my SMS Application not sending to the right number?

Tags: android

I'm inputting an 11 number phone number and i'm having trouble because it is not sending to the right number and I don't know why. Can you guys help me? Here is my code I don't really know the problem with it and I hope you guys can try to help me here

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
    private Button sendMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.send_message);
        final EditText phone = findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
        final EditText message = findViewById(R.id.message);
        sendMessage.setEnabled(false);

        if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg = message.getText().toString();
                String phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phonenumber)) {

                    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, msg, null, null);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a message and a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
        int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        return checkPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    sendMessage.setEnabled(true);
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not added the code to send an SMS.

Comment: What would be the code to send SMS sir, I badly want to know

Comment: SmsManager manager = SmsManager. getDefault(); manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);

Comment: Try this,  reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: Does it work now??

Answer (score 0):

To send the message,try this code, but first ask/check for SMS permissions:

```
SmsManager manager = SmsManager. getDefault(); 
manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent))